# Zend Form creation

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have 3 database tables like `rooms`, `room_type` and `room_status`. Here is the tables` structure

`rooms`

`room_id, room_number, room_type_id, room_status_id`

`room_type`

`room_type_id, room_type_name, room_type_desc`

`room_status`

`room_status_id, room_status_name, room_status_desc`

So, Actually based on this tables need to create form to add new room. I already has created rooms controller and model.

My thought is to create form based on the rooms table and create another two controller for room_type and for room status. After that get data from room_type and room_status and pass it to room form where i can create select element using this data.

Can you advice how can I achieve better solution. I am not that sure that this is good solution.

[EDIT]

`$status = $this->createElement('select', 'status');

```
    $status->setLabel("Select a status:");

    $status->addMultiOption('Active', 'active');

    $status->addMultiOption('Suspended', 'suspended');

    $this->addElement($status);`
```

As you can see here `addMultiOptionis` static, how to make it dynamic from the database? I hope I could explain you my idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, and I'm not sure I do. Setting Type and Status via a form would work in certain situations. 
First thing you might want to do would be to add a `room_status_id` to your `room` table, so you can track current status.

I'm imagining your context is a hotel or convention center type setting. In this context the room type will likely not change frequently, but the status may change several times a day.
So doing a form in like an admin console to setup the room and make initial type and status designations and the occasional change would be appropriate. For day to day operations you might want to include automatic status changes in your various controller actions.

Some psuedo code for example:

```
initiate room (admin): set room_type, set room_status;

reserve room: set room_status: reserved;
room in use: set room_status: in use;
room vacant: if (room != clean) {
    set room_status: not clean
} else {
    set room_status: clean
}

room being remodeled(admin)
if (room_type === change) {
  set type: new room_type;
} else {
  don't change room_type;
}
if (inRemodel === true) {
  set room_status: unavailable;
}
```

you probably don't need a controller for room_type and room_status as this info is unlikely to be changed or manipulated a lot.
room_type and room_status seem like they will be the kind of data that get set initially and then rarely change values. If that is the case the model would be the place to access these values and then just pass them where needed.

I hope I haven't missed the point completely.

[EDIT]
You asked how to display the names of room_type and room_status in your comment. You'd use a join:

```
//make a dbTable model for each table
//in your Application_Model_DbTable_Room, built a method similar to this to join the tables
public function fetchRoomData() {
        //setIntegrityCheck to false to allow joins
        $select = $this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)
                ->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE);
        //performs join aliasing table room_type to t
        $select->join(array('t' => 'room_type'), 't.room_type_id = room.room_type_id');
        ////performs join aliasing table room_status to s
        $select->join(array('s' => 'room_status'), 's.room_status_id = room.room_status_id');

        $result = $this->fetchAll($select);

        return $result;
    }
```

[EDIT]
To display a select form element based on a db table:

```
$bidlocation = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('room_type');
        $bidlocation->setLabel('Room Type: ');

        $b = new Application_Model_DbTable_RoomType();
        $a = $b->fetchAll();

        foreach ($a as $c) {
            //applies caps to first letter of each word
            $d = ucwords($c['room_type_name']);
            $bidlocation->addMultiOption($c['room_type_id'], $d);  
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually, I have created two new controller for room  status and room type. As you mentioned I attached room_type_id and room_status_id into rooms table. My problem is how to use status name and type name in the rooms form instead of using room_status_id  and room_type_id???

Comment: Like for example if the administrator wants to add new room. I have to create a form and in here there is supposed to be select with list of types and status. the id doesn't give anything to users

Comment: Yes this actually what I am looking for, but I need one more important things

Comment: you may have to access the column names as `$c->room_type_name` I think the method this is based on implemented `->toArray()` and fetchAll() usually returns an array of objects.